# Is there a way to 'set' a parameter in express routes from server?

Tags: node.js, express

My `app.post('/userSignUp')` retrieves user id from the database, after which I want to set it like this `/user/432874` from server itself. And then redirect it to route `/user/432874`. so far I'm setting it like this  `/user/ + userid` but running into  error when trying to do a `get` request on `/user/ + userid`. Why does this not work? Is there a way to do this?

Below is an example:

```
const userId;

app.post('/userSignUp', (req, resp, next) => {

  const HashQuery = {
      text: 'select * from users where session_id = $1',
      values: [req.cookies.hash_from_its_an_app]
  }

  client.query(HashQuery, (err, res) => {
      res.rows.map((i) => {
          userId = i.user_id;
      });
    resp.redirect('/user/'+ userId); // the browser stops here and doesn't go forward with GET
  }

}


app.get('/user/' + userId, (req, res) => {

    res.render('index');

});
```

error on the browser is this:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/user/10
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Comment: you should define a route with ```/user``` and userId as a path param, rather than creating one route per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change user endpoint to,

```
app.get('/user/:userId', (req, res) => {

//Get userId value by `req.params.userId`
   ...

});
```